# Mac - Script Text to a JSON file

Tags: json, bash, macos, scripting, push

noob here. I love scripting but this one is a little challenging. On the Mac, i need to be able to script/add text to a local users JSON file for all my Mac users. Local profile. I was told the sting i need to script/add needs to be placed at the end of the file. Need to add this:

`},"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"npstsu":false}}`

I've tried a few ways but i'm afraid that what i am doing is causing more damage to the actual file itself. Any thoughts on how i can achieve this so i can push this out to all our users?

Comment: Research how to use `jq` to add fields to a JSON file

Comment: The missing comma before `"protocol` is concerning.

Comment: If you don't want to install `jq`, the pre-installed python and ruby distributions should each have a JSON library.

Comment: oops! thanks @glennjackman. good eye!

Comment: Thanks for the `jq` suggestion. it was suggested to also try `sed`.

Comment: can you give the name of the file  you want to modify ?

Comment: JSON, like XML, demands a specific parser. sed or any other regex-based tool is insufficient in general

Comment: @EchoMike444 You bet, thanks for asking! The actual file we need to add a string to is located in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences I need to be able to add a `Protocol_Handler` string right before the 2 brackets at the end of the file. Doable?

Comment: This string needs to land right before the very last `}` of the users Preference file: `,"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"npstsu":false}}` but every time i try to script this, it either lands in the beginning of the file, no good, or behind the last `}`. Anyone?

Comment: after putting 2 and 2 together from the various posts i came up with this: `sed -i '.' '$s/}/},\"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"npstsu":false}}/'` Wondering what the `$` is doing to this? because when i remove it, it doesn't work.